# Is there an add-on to get better code formatting?

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, ide

I've used the Banner style indention scheme for years (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), but the last two releases of Microsoft Visual Studio no longer handle this correctly and all day long I'm having to manually reformat code which is a huge pain.

Does anyone know if there are add-on tools that support Banner style indention inside Visual Studio?

Or perhaps you've found a way to trick VS into handling Banner style correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Resharper can handle this.

Resharper has a ['Code Cleanup'](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html) feature that can reformat your entire code base according to your [indentation preferences](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html#Code_Style_Configuration_and_Sharing).

Comment: Thanks, I new it could reformat a section of code after you'd written it, I just wasn't sure if it could format it as you enter it.